# Linux DMA API - bandwidth of coherent memory and alternatives

Tags: linux, memory, dma

I am facing a problem that is causing me a strong headache. Ideas/suggestions are most welcome...

My current project is a device that performs image analysis. Images are captured by a camera attached to an FPGA. The FPGA is connected via PCI to an i.MX6Q processor (quad-core ARM Cortex-A9) with 1GB of memory.
The FPGA transfers images to CPU memory using DMA, and the CPU performs the image analysis.

The device will scan a sample, acquiring appr. 300 images. During the analysis, some 50 images need to be in CPU memory at the same time. Each image is 5MB in size.

The current design employs a custom Linux device driver which allocates a single contiguous DMA buffer using dma_alloc_coherent(). The FPGA transfers each image by DMA to this buffer, and the image is thereafter copied into a image buffer pool allocated by a user-space application. The copy operation is a simple memcpy().
It should be mentioned that our FPGA DMA controller does not support scatter/gather functionality. Therefore the need for a physically contiguous buffer as destination for the DMA operation.

The current solution works in principle, but performance is not satisfactory and needs improvement.

The main issue we are facing is an apparent bottleneck in memory bandwidth. The memcpy() operation that moves data from the buffer allocated by dma_alloc_coherent() into a standard malloc'ed buffer only yields appr. 80MB/sec.

I have searched the net on this subject and found other reports indicating the same problem. My understanding is that using a DMA coherent buffer effectively disables the CPU cache. Can anyone confirm this understanding? Is it a limitation specifically related to ARM and/or the i.MX6 processor?

Assuming that the memory bandwidth issue is unavoidable with DMA coherent memory, I have investigated other ways of achieving DMA transfers to a contiguous buffer that resides in cached RAM.

It should be noted that it is absolutely essential for the image analysis performance that the in-memory images are backed by the CPU cache. I.e. it is not a viable solution to expand the DMA-coherent buffer to accomodate all 50 in-memory images and perform the analysis in-place in that buffer if it is not backed by cache.

My next idea was to (somehow) obtain a contiguous buffer in cache-backed memory and use the streaming DMA API. It is my understanding that the streaming DMA API does exactly what I am looking for, that is, transferring the 'ownership' of a memory buffer between the device and CPU. I would expect the API is effectively used to invalidate cache lines for the DMA buffer when ownership of the buffer is transferred from device to CPU.

Can anyone confirm if this understanding is correct?

If yes, then what I basically need is a way of obtaining a contiguous buffer in normal cache-backed memory.

An obvious idea is to reserve memory at boot time (by specifying the 'mem' boot argument) and use mmap() to map it into user space. But my searches on this subject indicate that the memory bandwidth (cache?) issue is the same with this type of memory as it is for DMA-coherent memory.

Can anyone confirm (or even better, contradict) that memory bandwith is as limited for reserved, mmap'ed memory as it is for DMA coherent memory?

Another idea was to use Linux' CMA (Contiguous Memory Allocator) API, which looks promising (see https://lwn.net/Articles/396707/). But CMA requires a 3.18 kernel and unfortunately my system only has a 3.14 kernel.

Allocating contiguous memory at boot time could be another idea. But my driver is built as a module, and modules cannot allocate contiguous memory at boot time...

Which leaves me with no obvious solution for the issue. And a headache...
Can any of you experienced device driver developers give me an idea of how to transfer my images into memory as effectively as possible?

/Lars